# "Validation failed (numeric string is expected)" in NEstJS

Tags: nestjs, nest

I have no idea why this is happening but for some reason it is. I am not trying to validate anything special, same validation works on my other endpoints and it acts strange here, trying to validate something that is already valid

I am calling this route GET http://localhost:3333/messages?page=1&limit=20

Controller:

```
@ApiTags('Messages')
@UseGuards(JwtGuard)
@Controller('messages')
@ApiBearerAuth()
export class MessagesController {
  constructor(private messagesService: MessagesService) {}

  @Get()
  getMessages(
    @Query('conversationId', ParseIntPipe) conversationId: number,
    @Query('page', ParseIntPipe) page: number,
    @Query('limit', ParseIntPipe) limit: number,
  ) {
    return this.messagesService.getMessages(conversationId, page, limit);
  }

  @Get('conversations')
  getConversations(@GetUser('id', ParseIntPipe) userId: number) {
    return this.messagesService.getConversations(userId);
  }

  @Post()
  addNewMessage(@Body() dto: AddMessageDto) {
    return this.messagesService.addNewMessage(dto);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing a `conversationId` as a part of your query. There's no optional setting, so you have to pass it